# Codeigniter 3 - how to generate formated price xml

Tags: xml, codeigniter

For store front I use this function to get formated price:

```
<?php echo price_formatted(calculate_product_price($product->price, $product->discount_rate), $product->currency, false); ?>
<?php else:
if (!empty($product->discount_rate)): ?>
<?php echo price_formatted($product->price, $product->currency, true); ?>
```

With this function I generate feed XML:

```
public function generate_google_post()
    {

    $xml   = '<channel>';
    $query = $this->sitemap_model->get_all_products();

    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $xml .= '<item>
            <g:id>'.$row['id'].'</g:id>
            <title>'.$row['title'].'</title>
            <link>https://mywebtest.com/'.$row['slug'].'</link>
            <g:price>'.$row['price'].' PLN</g:price>
            <description>'.$row['description'].'</description>
            <g:product_type>'.$row['category_id'].'</g:product_type>
            <g:google_product_category>'.$row['category_id'].'</g:google_product_category>
            <g:image_link>htts://mywebtest.com/upload/images'.$row['image_default'].'</g:image_link>
            <g:condition>new</g:condition>
            <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
            <g:brand>'.$row['brand'].'</g:brand>
            <g:mpn>'.$row['sku'].'</g:mpn>
            <g:gtin>'.$row['ean'].'</g:gtin>
        </item>';
    }

    $xml .= '</channel>';

    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xml"');

    echo $xml;
    }
```

and the problem is currently I get output price without formatted.

1. How to implement above function to format price and then generate output?

Comment: you need to format your `$row['price']` in your *generate_google_post function*. Check [php number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 0):

use below code
`number_format($row['price'], 2, '.', '');`
in your generate_google_post function.
I hope that you will get solution.